# Modifying Registry on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

Say you log as administrator to a Windows 7 and modify a value in its Registry (regedit).

Then logoff, and then User X login to that Windows 7. User X has no administration privileges.

Will User X have the same Registry that was modified by administrator user?

Comment: It depends what exactly you changed.  We need more information be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on the registry key you're editing. Those under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE are per machine, and will affect all users. Those edited under HKEY_CURRENT_USER are per user, and are independent and would need changing for each user - they won't need administrative rights to edit these keys though.